# Why is ActiveRecord::Base#update_attributes deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I noticed in the Rails docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) that the `update_attributes` method is deprecated:

> This method is deprecated on the latest stable version of Rails. The last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown here.

I'm curious to know why it was deprecated and what is preferred in its place.

It isn't a matter of enormous consequence for me right now as the method works fine in my Rails 2.x apps. However, in anticipation of upgrading to Rails 3 some day I'd like to start getting a grasp on what I'll need to change and how things are done differently.

Comment: Another part of APIDock documentation does not list it as deprecated [Old](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) vs [New](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes)

Comment: APIDock now lists the Active Resource version in its "similar methods" list.

Comment: Better hurry -- you're about to have to go from Rails 2 to Rails 4. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/20/rails-master-is-now-4-0-0-beta/

Comment: The "similar methods" of APIDock are not necessarily similar. They are just similarly named. ActiveRecord and ActiveResource is not really related (apart from both being part of Rails (yet)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apidock is a little misleading, it actually says "deprecated or moved"; the latter is true, the former is not. `ActiveRecord::Base` includes `ActiveRecord::Persistence`, which defines #update_attributes. You can view the docs for this on apidock at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes.

While this is also in ActiveResource now, there's no shared implementation of update_attributes, and you shouldn't look there for ActiveRecord::Base-related documentation, or vice versa.

Comment: As an additional remark: `ActiveRecord::Persistence` is included into `ActiveRecord::Base`. So in fact nothing changed, apart from the physical place of the method definition.

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 6 it became really deprecated. The reasons was discussed here:

> https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31998

The explanation is that both update_attributes and update_attributes! are just alias for update and update! for years and they can sound confusing (because of their singular versions: update_attribute).