# Rails: Is there an update or update_attributes that throws exception on failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there an equivalent of `model.update` or `model.update_attributes` that throws an exception on failure?

Seems there's not an `update!` or `update_attributes!`

Comment: Are you sure you've tried `update_attributes!`? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think there is no `update_attributes!` because there is. If you were reading the apidock you might have come across an issue such as they talked about here:
[Why is ActiveRecord::Base#update_attributes deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774512/why-is-activerecordbaseupdate-attributes-deprecated)

Here are the docs detailing the method you want:
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes%21

But, yes, there is an `update_attributes!` that will raise an exception on validation failure. It calls `save!` under the hood.

Comment: Reason I asked is because I was getting an error undefined `update_attributes!`.

Comment: Nno there's no update! method. Are you sure an ActiveRecord model was throwing that exception?

Comment: Well i used to be 100%, but not I can't re-create.

Answer (score 9):

Just an update.. on `update!` :)

[update!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21) exists since Rails 4 and [update_attributes!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes-21), which was available since Rails 3, has since become just an alias for `update!`.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion here is that there is no update! on ActiveRecord::Relation
but there is on a model

```
## On a Model
User.find_by_id(1).update(name: 'xx')    # works
User.find_by_id(1).update!(name: 'xx')   # works

## On a Relation
User.where(id: 1).update(name: 'xx')     # works
User.where(id: 1).update!(name: 'xx')    # doesn't work
```

It's not uncommon to get Model and Relationship types mixed up